# How do I get started writing my own IP-Like Protocol?

Tags: c++, c, networking, ip, protocols

So my question is, would it be possible to write a protocol which does the same as the Internet Protocol, and if so, how do I get started? And don't say, "isn't the Internet Protocol good enough?", yes it is, it is just to see if it is possible:P

I would like to know a bit more about how, 
just for learning how protocols are done. I have some experience in programming, but not anything like networking protocols.

Comment: Your question probably should be "How do I get started writing my own IP-Like Protocol?"

Comment: Ok thanks, i wasn't sure:P, so as @vcsjones said how would i do something like that?

Comment: No, it's not possible. The Universe just won't work with two IP-like protocols around.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: As the IETF has pretty comprehensively proven by trying and failing to popularize IPv6 ;-) But seriously, nobody's going to use it until IPv4 goes away due to address exhaustion.

Comment: @SteveJessop: which has already supposedly happened...

Comment: @Jerry: I've got about 20 IPv4 addresses at the moment for servers at work, and I can get another one any time I like from any of several suppliers. IANA may be out of IPv4 addresses, but people who set up web servers aren't, so people who set up web servers on the whole don't use IPv6. The crucial insight for me was when someone pointed out that IPv6 isn't really "the other protocol". It's "the other internet", so to get someone to use it you have to persuade them to get on the other internet as well as the one everyone's on already. But this is vastly off-topic, sorry for banging on.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I think the larger problem is that the scarcity of IPv4 addresses makes them a fairly large money-maker. IPv6's success depends heavily on people who will probably lose a great deal of revenue when it comes into use.

Comment: @Jerry: indeed. Someone who *doesn't* have a vast IPv4 block needs to be the disruptor who turns IPv6 into something worth having. We don't use whale oil in lamps any more, so I know it will happen. I just don't know when. I don't even know when the first non-trivial website will be created that doesn't have an IPv4 address, let alone when IPv6 will start to dominate, when Teredo can be switched off, and other such milestones.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I agree it'll happen. FWIW, there are major servers with no IPv4 addresses already -- 4G LTE mobile phones all use IPv6, and some servers intended specifically for them only have v6 addresses.

Comment: @Jerry: good point, "non-trivial" was the wrong criterion (since device type lockin is not a feature of a happily-functioning internet, but doesn't make a site or service trivial). I wonder whether IPv4-IPv6 migration will end up being presented in terms of non-mobile connections "joining up with LTE".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is yes -- it has been done, and could be done again.

Examples of what have been done include DECnet, NetBIOS, Appletalk, and ATM. Although I'm not sure it was ever fully implemented as intended (though DECNet came pretty close), the standard OSI 7-layer model for networking was originally *intended* as a model of actual implementation (i.e., the intent was that people would implement those layers, and you'd be able to build a fully network stack by plugging together the implementation of your choice of each layer).

Of course, what most of us think of as IP today is really IPv4 -- as you can probably guess from the version number, it had predecessors (and a successor, IPv6).

Edit: as to *how* you do it: pretty much like anything else. I'd start by writing up something about your motivation -- what you want to accomplish, what sorts of operations it should support, etc. Then start working on the simplest design you can figure out that can possibly do what you want. Then, as you use it and encounter problems, figure out whether they stem from poor implementation, or shortcomings in the design itself. Modify one or both as needed, trying to keep its evolution as coherent and understandable as possible.

Comment: Why does the OSI 7-layer model make me think of bean salad?

Comment: @JohnDibling: Probably from too much time working with networking via Java Beans (where "any" is "too much").

Comment: IPsec is arguably an important network layer for the list, since it's a hive of activity.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yup -- I was sticking to others that were clearly different from IP.

Answer (score 1):

In short: Yes, it would be possible. On a higher level (i.e. OSI layer 7) it is done daily. If you want to implement the next IP, all you need are:

- Special hardware (for the actual physical implementation, assuming that your protocol greatly differs from IP)
- Device drivers for your favourite operating system that support your protocol
- Maybe a high-level API to facilitate implementation

Edit: Saw that two others beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

> would it be possible to write a protocol which does the same as the
>   Internet Protocol?

Yes it is possible to write your own IP stack, but it is extremely difficult to actually go ahead and do it (and actually do it right) unless you are an expert level both in programming and in networking